# How to require all files from a Rails task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am writing a Rails task that is using all the models in an application. When I required all the models files, I still get errors like `NameError: uninitialized constant ComputerHelper`

What can you do in order to load all Rails files or perhaps initialize Rails, similar to whatever happens when starting up the Rails console?

Answer (score 0):

Are you starting your tasks with `task :taskname => :environment do`?

I believe the `:environment` should handle all that for you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include your helper module in your rake task file.

```
# app/helpers/computer_helper.rb
module ComputerHelper
  def foo_bar
    return "foo bar"
  end
end

# lib/tasks/test.rake
require "#{Rails.root}/app/helpers/computer_helper"
include ComputerHelper

namespace :test do
  task(:foo => :environment) do
    foo_bar
  end
end
```